# Build android app with Qt5 failed (missing headers)

Tags: android, 64-bit, qt5

Trying to build android app from windows 7 64bit

I don't want to compile the Qt source again, so I just downloaded the binary distribution:

Qt 5.1.0 for Android (Windows 32-bit, 716 MB)

After configured Qt Creator with the Android SDK path and Android NDK path

I opened an example and tried to build

Then I got the following errors:

```
D:\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\android_armv7\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:80: error:
algorithm: No such file or directory
```

I searched thru the algorithm header a bit in the Qt directory, it could be found at:

```
D:\Qt5.1.0\Tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++
```

I don't what I did wrong? Am I not supposed to use the 32bit binary distribution on 64bit win7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the problem is that I was using android-ndk-r8, which is pretty old

After I downloaded and used android-ndk-r8e, the build problem is gone.